# How to automatically generate c++ headers

Tags: c++, header

Given foo.hpp

```
class Foo
{
public:
   void MethodA()
   {
        //BODY IMPLEMENTATION
   }
   int MerhodB()
   {
       return 2+3;
   }
}
```

I need a tool to generate two files foo.cpp and foo.hpp. Such as

foo.hpp

```
class Foo
{
public:
   void MethodA();
   int MerhodB();
}
```

foo.cpp

```
void Foo::MethodA()
{
     //BODY IMPLEMENTATION
}
int Foo::MerhodB()
{
    return 2+3;
}
```

I tried Lazy c++ but it is not working for me. Any other suggestions?

Edit: I don't use Windows so please avoid Visual Studio tools. Thanks

Comment: Stupid question: Why? Do you have a lot of sources written in a single file? Just wondering :)

Comment: @Bart It is easier to write a first scratch implementation of something in one file and it is good to have some tool for separation of declaration and definition.

Comment: @Bart Unfortunately, yes. I use emacs and was too lazy to update header file every time I change a method declaration. So I decided to write it in Java/c# style. Now "someone" asks me to convert it to conventional separate header/implementation style.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase this question as:  Why isn't lzz parsing this code correctly - and then provide the piece of code you're trying to get through lzz.  From your comments above, it appears that you're using lzz incorrectly.  You need to separate pure C++ code from preprocessor using $hdr-$end/$src-$end blocks.

Comment: Any solution for this, 12 years later? I'm interested too :)

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2005 with Visual Assist X (or newer)

You write everything in the `.hpp` file and then you can use the "Move implementation to source" refactoring function from the popup menu if you right click on your method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell. I'm a linux guy. I'll update the question :)